# How to solve the SQL error: "Every derived table must have its own alias" in case of joins

Tags: sql, join, alias

I am using this query:

```
select max(counted)
from (select max(outcome.player_of_match) counted 
from outcome 
inner join player
on player.id=outcome.player_of_match group by player.id);
```

It shows the SQL error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an alias to the subquery you're selecting from:

```
select max(T1.counted)
from   (
          select     max(outcome.player_of_match) counted 
          from       outcome 
          inner join player
                  on player.id=outcome.player_of_match 
          group by   player.id
       ) AS T1;
```